# is the function $||x||_0$ a norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I know that the function $||x||_0$ is defined as the number of nonzero entries in $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Then is the function $||x||_0$ a valid norm?

I think FALSE, because we have that

$||ax|| \neq |a|||x||$ for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

However, I want to be more certain.

Comment: You are correct, it is not a norm.  $\|x\|_p$ is also not a norm when $0 < p < 1$.

Comment: To show that it is not a norm, you need to exhibit a specific counter-example to one of the norm axioms. You have chosen the right axiom, but you haven't given specific values of $a$ and $x$ that give a counter-example. ($\|ax\| = |a|\|x\|$ does hold for some $a$ and $x$.) For a specific counter-example, you could take $a = 2$ and $x = (1, 1, \ldots, 1))$. Then $\|ax\| = n \neq |a|\|x\| = 2n$ (unless $n =0$ when you do get a norm).